# Pumping lemma (context-free) of $L = \{a^nb^{\max\{n,m\}}a^m\ |\ n, m ≥ 0\}$

Tags: context-free-grammar, pumping-lemma

I want to show that $L = \{a^nb^{\max\{n,m\}}a^m\ |\ n, m ≥ 0\}$ is not context-free.

I tried with things like take $w=a^pb^pa^p$ and got that $vwz$ is $a^qb^{p-q}$ but... I don't know, it doesn't seem right to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $p$ is the pumping length, let $w=a^pb^pa^p$. If $L$ is context-free, it is possible to write $w=uvxyz$ in such a way that $|vy|\ge 1$, $|vxy|\le p$, and $uv^kxy^kz\in L$ for every integer $k\ge 0$. Now consider cases.

- If $vxy$ lies entirely within the block of $b$s or one of the blocks of $a$s, $uv^2xy^2z\notin L$: if $vxy$ lies in one of the $a$ blocks, $uv^2xy^2z$ has too few $b$s, and if it lies in the $b$ block, $uv^2xy^2z$ has too many $b$s.
- If $vxy$ contains both $a$s and $b$s, then $uxz\notin L$, because it contains too few $b$s. (Always remember that it’s possible to pump down, by setting $k=0$, as well as up.)

Comment: I don't understand the last case: Why $uxz \notin L$? if $|uxz|=0$ you have $a^0b^0c^0$, and that's right

Comment: @AndréKuljis: $uxz$ clearly cannot be empty: $|vy|\le|vxy|\le p$, and $|w|=3p$, so there are at least $2p$ characters in $uxz$. The point is that $vxy$ can intersect at most one of the blocks of $a$s, so the other one will still have $p$ $a$s after you pump down to $uxz$, but there will be fewer than $p$ $b$s.

Comment: Bro, if $2p \le |uxz| \le 3p$ and $p=0$, $|uxz|=0$

Comment: @AndréKuljis: The pumping length is never $0$.

Comment: That works to me, thank you!

Comment: @AndréKuljis: You’re welcome.